# How to find and replace specific elements in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a *numpy* array: `a = [[1, 999, 3], [-1, 1, 3], [2, 999, 6]]`

I want to find every instance of number *999* and replace it with the average of the two neighbouring numbers (*999* is always in the middle).

I used the following code to try and make this work: `np.where(a == 999, .5 * (a[0] + a[2]), a)`

But the output I get appends the value I calculate for the first array: `[[1, 2, 3], [-1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 6]]` instead of:`[[1, 2, 3], [-1, 1, 3], [2, 4, 6]]`

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are all of your arrays 3x3, or do you need a more general solution?

Comment: For this specific problem they are all 3x3 yes, but more general solution would be good too (since I'm learning).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the row indices where the second column equals `999`, and replace with the mean of the respective first and third columns. I'm using [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) here to avoid integer based indexing, this will instead create a mesh from the input sequences:

```
a = np.array([[1, 999, 3], [-1, 1, 3], [2, 999, 6]])

ix = a[:,1] == 999
a[ix, 1] = a[np.ix_(ix, [0,2])].mean(1)
```

---

```
print(a)

array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  1,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  6]])
```

Comment: Can you explain np.ix_ a bit more? I am not sure I understand it?

Comment: What `np.ix_` does here is create an array containing all the pairs of indexes.
`ix` is a list containing the index of the rows where there is a `999`. So by giving `np.ix_` `ix` and `[0, 2]` we are asking `np.ix_` to generate the indexes of the values. 

In that case: `ix => [0, 2]`, `np.ix_(ix, [0, 2]) =>  [[0], [2]], [[0, 2]]`, `a[np.ix_(ix, [0, 2])] => [[a[0, 0], a[0, 2]], [a[2, 0], a[2, 2]]]`

Comment: You might find useful to check this section of the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing @urbanpečoler